Transition function of the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n_k$
This problem comes from Vakil 17.1.H (Jul3123 version).

Problem 17.1.H. Suppose $k$ is a field. Define the subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k\times \mathbb{P}^n_k$ corresponding to points on the corresponding line of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, so that the fiber of $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ corresponding to a point $l=[x_o:\cdots:x_n]$ is the line in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k$ corresponding to $l$. Show that $\pi$ is the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

My question. I am mostly unsure how to describe the section of $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ on the distinguished affine $D_+(x_i)$.
My attempts. Following the hint of using transition functions, I tried to check the transition function of the sheaf of sections of $\pi$, as that would give a locally free sheaf corresponding to this "vector bundle". For $D_+(x_i)\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n_k$, there is
$$\Gamma(D_+(x_i),\mathscr{S}):= \{ \sigma:D_+(x_i)\to X|\pi\sigma =id \} $$
Here such $\sigma$ takes $D_+(x_i)$ to $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\times D_+(x_i)\cong \operatorname{Spec}k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\otimes_k k[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]/(\frac{x_i}{x_i}-1)$
which is equivalent to a ring map
$$ k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\otimes_k k[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]/(\frac{x_i}{x_i}-1)\to k[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]/(\frac{x_i}{x_i}-1) $$
I do not know how to define the ring map so that the section takes the point to the line plus the point, namely $[a_0:\cdots:a_n]\to  (\{ (\lambda a_0,\cdots,\lambda,\cdots,\lambda x_n)|\lambda\in k \},[a_0:\cdots:a_n]) $
Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

$X$ is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb A^{n+1}\times \mathbb P^n$, so the coordinate rings (denoting $x_{ij}=x_i/x_j$ on $x_j\neq0$) $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\otimes k[x_{0j},\ldots,x_{nj}]$ are also subject to relations of the form $x_i = x_{ij}x_j$. After quotienting the relations you will be left with coordinate rings isomorphic to $k[x_j]\otimes k[x_{0j},\ldots,x_{nj}]$ on charts of $X$.
The projection map corresponds to the inclusion of the second factor, so that sections over $x_j\neq0$ are equivalent to maps $k[x_j] \to k[x_{0j},\ldots,x_{nj}]$.
